# Why is the Facebook "like" code submission telling me that our FB page url is incorrect?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-page, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

Trying to obtain a "like box" code to apply to our website. When I enter the facebook url of our page (copy/paste from browser), I am getting an error telling me that it is incorrect. I have tried several variations of urls thinking that it was because I was logged into our account but nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong?

On the page to obtain the code for the like box, it asks for facebook page url. I pasted in the url that was in the address bar of our homepage and when that didn't work, I tried variations of our name but none of it has worked. Our facebook page is Harrison Mechanical & Electrical, Inc. I've tried facebook.com/pages/Harrison-Mechanical-Electrical-Inc/…, tried taking off the numbers at the end, tried removing "pages", tried facebook.com/harrison, facebook.com/harrisonmechanical, facebook.com/harrisonmechanical&electrical.....

Comment: Please add more details, such as the url you are trying or the whole code block you are using..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's very hard to tell what you're doing wrong when you haven't shown us what you're doing at all. Please edit your question to provide those details; as it is, your question is pretty much unanswerable (pretty much, because a perfectly valid answer would be "you're putting in an incorrect URL", which wouldn't be very helpful to you). Thanks. :)

Comment: On the page to obtain the code for the like box, it asks for facebook page url. I pasted in the url that was in the address bar of our homepage and when that didn't work, I tried variations of our name but none of it has worked. Our facebook page is Harrison Mechanical & Electrical, Inc. I've tried http://www.facebook.com/pages/Harrison-Mechanical-Electrical-Inc/290514827625424, tried taking off the numbers at the end, tried removing "pages", tried facebook.com/harrison, facebook.com/harrisonmechanical, facebook.com/harrisonmechanical&electrical.....

Comment: I worked fine for me.  `<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Harrison-Mechanical-Electrical-Inc/290514827625424" data-width="500" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>` Maybe your app id of the app you have is still in sandbox mode?

Comment: Not sure what the problem was but it is working now. I'm going to add it to our website and hopefully it too will work. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I worked fine for me.

`<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Harrison-Mechanical-Electrical-Inc/290514827625424" data-width="500" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true"></div>`

Maybe your app id of the app you have is still in sandbox mode?